# 403 Forbidden issue using Rally rest api for java

Tags: rally

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava

We are currently using RallyRestToolkitForJava to retrieve the details. The code is working properly but seems to have interim issues with the 403 Forbidden exception .We are able to hit the service and retrieve the details using a standalone java program and also by a web app. we are currently using the API KEY concept for authentication. however interim we are facing this issue and is impacting stability and is a definite problem for stability. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
//Using Rally REST API, URL need a http proxy as well
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(rallydevurl, apikey);
URI uri = new URI(httpproxyurl);
restApi.setProxy(uri, proxyuser, proxypassword);

restApi.setApplicationName(rallyAppName);
QueryRequest projects = new QueryRequest("projects");
projects.setFetch(new Fetch(projectArrayList)));
QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(projects); // Fails here..
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the 403 is on your end?  Something weird going on with your proxy?  It's probably worth following up with Rally support to see if we can see the 403s in our logs or not.